# How do i create a Python HTTP server to host a file inside it?

Tags: python, json, database, http, httpserver

I'm trying to make a program. This program will have the functionality to host a file in an HTTP server but I couldn't find a way to make it.

This HTTP server will host a JSON file in it.

And I wanted to make a program that sends a request to that server and then reads everything inside that server directory.

I tried many attempts and messed around with Python but I can't find the correct way to make it

Answer (score 1):

This is already included in the standard library. Just run this in your terminal from the directory you want to serve:

```
python -m http.server
```

This is not recommended for product use, however, if you need to run this in production it is better to use a real HTTP server like Apache or NGINX anway.